# Multiple ddslick drop down menus at the same time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

If I have one dropdown menu, I can used this "ddData.selectedData.text" to get the text very well. But when I use some drop down menus at the same time (use the same "var ddData" ), then I tried to get the selectedData in each of them, it can no longer recognized the data.

```
for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
$('#dropdownBasico'+i).ddslick({
data: ddData,
width: 150,
imagePosition: "left",
selectText: "How r u ?",
onSelected: function(data){

                 if(data.selectedIndex >= 0) {
                                  ddData = $('#dropdownBasico'+i).data('ddslick');
                                   alert('Selected text: '+ddData.selectedData.text); //this will give no result !
```

Any one knows what is wrong here ?

Comment: Looks like its the only question got no answer in stackoverflow. Someone, pls help !!!

Comment: Hello, Is there any body knows it ?

Comment: I either send this question to ddslick githup and also tweet and blog comment this author @chaudharyp and http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick but no one could give me the answer! Is it that complex or is it a bug that is not fixed that they never give a response ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with multiple select. I don't know if you have the same problem. I fixed it like this:

```
$('.your-class').each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).ddslick({
                ... options ...
            });
        });
```